# Full calendar set dayNames with API/props

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I am using Vue component of Fullcalender and I cant find an option to change default day names.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayNames

I tried to pass props likes this:

```
<FullCalendar
   :option="{
     dayNames:[
     'Sunday',
     'Monday', 
     'Tuesday', 
     'Wednesday',
     'Thursday', 
     'Friday', 
     'Saturday'
   ]}"
/>
```

or

```
<FullCalendar
   :dayNames="['Sunday',
            'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
            'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']"
/>
```

but it didn't work. I don't know how to pass them to component.

Comment: Are you using this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue  ? Because it seems this plugin loads fullCalendar version 4. The `dayNames` option was removed in version 4 (for info about that, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3). That's probably why it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick function using jQuery to do this:

```
var headerElems = $('.fc-day-header');

if (headerElems.length > 0) {

    headerElems.each((k, v) => {

        var text = $('span', v).text();

        // set first chart as text
        $('span', v).text(text[0]);

    });

}
```